# Finding integral of P(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

When $0\le x\le 1, P(x) = 2$.

When $x>1, P(x) = -\frac{2}{x}$

Then what is $$\int P(x)\,dx$$

I could not find the second part when $x > 1$.

Comment: know that the integral of 1/x dx is the absolute value of the natural log of x.  Hope that helps.

Comment: $P(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2&\text{if}&0<x\le1\\
\frac{-2}x&\text{if}&x>1
\end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 4):

it is $\int\frac{-2}{x}dx=-2\ln(x)+C$
the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{x}dx$ doesn't exist

Comment: but it has boundaries from 1 to infinity, isn't it?

Comment: this is the indefinite integral

Comment: This is the indefinite integral for when $x>1$, right?

Comment: yes indeed the first is the indefinite integral

Comment: it is not indefinite why should be  ? e.g. it is indicated that for the first part x is between 0<=x<=1  if there is a initial condition such as x = 1 is that still indefinite?

Answer (score 0):

Expressing $P(x)$ using indicator functions, we integrate each term individually.
$$\begin{align}
P(x) & = 2 \operatorname {\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(x) - \frac 2 x\operatorname {\bf 1}_{(1,\infty)}(x)
\\[3ex]\therefore
\int P(x)\operatorname d x & = (2 x+C_1) \operatorname {\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(x) + (C_2-2\ln (x)) \operatorname {\bf 1}_{(1,\infty)}(x)
\\ & = 2 x \operatorname {\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(x) + (2-2\ln (x)) \operatorname {\bf 1}_{(1,\infty)}(x)+ C
\\[3ex]\therefore
\int_0^z P(x)\operatorname d x 
 & = 2 z \operatorname {\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(z) + (2-2\ln (z)) \operatorname {\bf 1}_{(1,\infty)}(z)
\end{align}$$